# State, Country design question

Tags: design

There a few ways to give a user a choice of countries and states. I can name 3

1) Populate standard picklist

2) User SF new picklist feature

3) Create Country/State object and dataload a list of countries/states. Have 3 custom fields, state, country, parent country (lookup field to the same object) where you can then have each state linked to a country.

Can anyone explain when is best to use which method? Is there a best practice and explain why it is so?

Thanks

Comment: Using the standard fields with state and country picklists turned on (presumably your option 1) means that you get the picklists in both standard salesforce pages and in Visualforce and with no field duplication.

Comment: So what I am taking from your answer that standard state and country picklists are the method of choice when designing a solution? Can you see benefits from the other two ways mentioned that have an advantage to consider?

Comment: Someone else will have to do that; embracing the platform features is usually the lowest risk approach. But check if you have requirements that the platform features don't cover.

Comment: I'm with Keith C here; using platform features leads to more predictability as you expand your sfdc org's ecosystem with 3rd party apps or 3rd party system integrations

Comment: I accept Keith's answer and would have marked it as such but I only see it as a comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends what you want to achieve. If you only have a handful of options for the countries and states then my suggestion would be to use a picklist field. If you would want to store more complex information such as country code, country owner based on certain criteria, or to have some sort of relationship between the state, country and your number of possible countries is significant higher it would make much more sense to create a a custom object for the country. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Marc, this helped me a lot. I was also looking for a design answer besides Keith's best practice answer. This gives me a way to break down the design and be able to justify the client why I choose what I did. Kudos.